# MVC 5 routing - on route change incorrect url shows up

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I got a problem with MVC 5 routing, when I access url `www.mysite.com/car/controller/action` that matches my custom route (correct controller action is being triggered) - Url itself(no redirection) immediately changes to `www.mysite.com`. In my layout page I have `<base href="/">` tag  and I'm thinking that this might causing this strange behavior...

How can I fix that?

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "null",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
    routes.MapRoute(
                "carRoute",
                "car/{controller}/{action}"
                );
    routes.MapRoute(
                 "trainRoute",
                 "train/{controller}/{action}"
             );
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "angular",
        url: "{*.}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Comment: try changing the sequence of routes. Put carRoute first then trainRoute then angular and put first route in the end,

Comment: Can you post the code for the action that is being invoked? also can you remove the <base href="/"> tag and try again

Comment: #Ankush Jain changing sequence didn't help. #Haitham Shaddad removing base tag didn't help as well, action returns View simple html.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what was causing the problem, below angular code was messing up my url. Removed it and problem gone.

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```